# Cassandra - do not upsert

Tags: cassandra

We have a requirement where we would like our application (which might be deployed on multiple hosts) to create a row in Cassandra. The only host which is successful in creating the row, execute the work. Would it be enough to write an insert statement like below so that if two server try to insert the row, only one succeeds, and the other one gets the exception/does not succeed?

`INSERT INTO keyspace1.claim (claim_id, status) VALUES (1, false) IF NOT EXIST`

Would like to understand using `IF NOT EXIST` will avoid the upsert.

Thanks,
Shilpa

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `IF NOT EXISTS` will include a paxos round and read-before-write though so much much slower. Check the resultset of the insert with `wasApplied()` to tell if it took or not.

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0

Comment: Thank you, Christ Lohfink for the answer and the link!